# Registering closed types with unity

Tags: unity-container, registration

I have the following interface

```
public interface IViewModelFactory<out TViewModel>
{
    TViewModel Create();
}
```

and I have several classes that will implement this interface as in

```
public class LeaseCreateViewModelFactory : IViewModelFactory<LeaseCreateModel>
{

    public LeaseCreateModel Create()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class LeaseEditViewModelFactory : IViewModelFactory<LeaseEditModel>
    {

        public LeaseEditModel Create()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How can I register all the closed types that implement the IViewModelFactory with Unity, I've looked but all I can find is individual registrations of the closed type.

Found on the Microsoft documentation how to do this for individual registrations
like:

```
container.RegisterType<IValidator<StockQuote>, RandomStockQuoteValidator>();
```

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this link

http://www.danderson00.com/2010/09/automatically-register-implementors-of.html

I was hoping I could do this without resorting to extensions but it works...

```
public static void RegisterAllTypesForOpenGeneric(this IUnityContainer container, Type openGenericType, Assembly targetAssembly)
{
      if (!openGenericType.IsGenericTypeDefinition) throw new ArgumentException("typeToRegister must be an open generic type", "typeToRegister");

         foreach (Type type in targetAssembly.GetExportedTypes())
         {
             if (openGenericType.IsInterface)
                  RegisterInterfaceTypes(container, openGenericType, type, type);
             else
                  RegisterBaseTypes(container, openGenericType, type, type);           
         }
}

private static void RegisterInterfaceTypes(IUnityContainer container, Type openGenericType, Type targetType, Type typeToRegister)
{
    foreach (Type interfaceType in targetType.GetInterfaces())
    if (interfaceType.IsGenericType && !interfaceType.ContainsGenericParameters && openGenericType.IsAssignableFrom(interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
         container.RegisterType(interfaceType, typeToRegister);
}

private static void RegisterBaseTypes(IUnityContainer container, Type openGenericType, Type targetType, Type typeToRegister)
{
     if (targetType.BaseType != null && targetType.BaseType != yypeof(object))
         if (targetType.BaseType.IsGenericType && openGenericType.IsAssignableFrom(targetType.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
              container.RegisterType(targetType.BaseType, typeToRegister);
    else
        RegisterBaseTypes(container, openGenericType, targetType.BaseType, typeToRegister);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Registration by Convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507479%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) by using the extension method `RegisterTypes`.

First add the following methods to locate your concrete types and implemented interfaces:

```
private static IEnumerable<Type> GetImplementedIViewModelFactoryTypes(Type type)
{
    return type.GetInterfaces().Where(iface => iface.IsGenericType &&
        iface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IViewModelFactory<>));
}

private static bool ImplementsIViewModelFactory(Type type)
{
    return GetImplementedIViewModelFactoryTypes(type).Any();
}

private IEnumerable<Type> GetConcreteFactoryTypes()
{
    // You may want to change which assemblies are scanned here
    return AllClasses.FromAssemblies(typeof(IViewModelFactory<>).Assembly)
        .Where(ImplementsIViewModelFactory);
}
```

Then you may use this like so:

```
container.RegisterTypes(GetConcreteFactoryTypes(), GetImplementedIViewModelFactoryTypes);
```

This will automatically wire up all of your `IViewModelFactory<T>` implementations. They can then be resolved as normal:

```
var leaseEditViewModelFactory = container.Resolve<IViewModelFactory<LeaseEditViewModel>>();
```